# How to split a string with letters and numbers into different variables using js?

Tags: javascript

Given the following string:

```
var myString = "s1a174o10";
```

I would like to have the following result:

```
var s = 1;
var a = 174;
var o = 10;
```

Each letter on the string matches the following number.

Keep in mind that the string is not static, here is another example:

```
var myString = "s1p5a100";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with regex:

```
var vars = {};
myString.replace(/(\D+)(\d+)/g, function(_,k,v){ vars[k] = +v });

console.log(vars); //=> {s: 1, a: 174, o: 10}
```

Comment: mmm... using `replace` for something that is not a replace? That falls into the too nasty of a hack for me....

Comment: `replace` for looping matches is common practice in my book... I find the `while(assignment)` pattern harder to read TBH.

Comment: I agree that the assignment in the `while` can be confusing. While it is pretty commmon, I also stay away from that. I'd prefer something like `var matches = myString.match(/(\D+)(\d+)/g)`; `for (var i=1; i < matches.length; i+=2) { vars[matches[i]] = +matches[i+1]}`

Comment: @JuanMendes: That's fine until you encounter a string like `"s{1}a{174}o{10}"` to match with `/(\D+)\{(\d+)\}/g`. Now you either resort to the `while` loop or keep using the `replace` pattern which will work in both cases. That's why I use it, it's consistent and easier to read. When I see a `replace` with no assignment I immediately think, "oh, regex loop".

Comment: Btw, John Resig has an old (2008) post about this usage of `replace` http://ejohn.org/blog/search-and-dont-replace/

Comment: @elclans I must admit, it's not that nasty, just seems wrong... Also I have to admit, I didn't understand that `(/(\D+)(\d+)/g).exec("s1a174o10")` returns only the first match, you have to call exec again to get the next match. +1 for showing me that I need to read up on this. I think I prefer this "hacked" version than the assignment in the while condition...

Comment: Great answer and cool discussion! @elclanrs Could you explain what the _ parameter is?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter It's the matched substring (s1, a174, k is the first parenthesized expression (s) and v is the second parenthesized expression (1) See http://jsfiddle.net/2YL3z/3/

Comment: I give up, using `replace` for looping matches is now acceptable in my book too, thanks for a good lesson!

Comment: @JuanMendes: You can have the best of both worlds. You need a `gmatch` helper using this technique and you're golden. I put a lil' demo here: http://jsbin.com/iredog/1/edit

Answer (score 5):

You could use a regular expression:

```
var ITEM = /([a-z])(\d+)/g;
```

Then put each match into an object:

```
var result = {};
var match;

while(match = ITEM.exec(myString)) {
    result[match[1]] = +match[2];
}
```

Now you can use `result.s`, `result.a`, and `result.o`.

Answer (score 0):

Regex can help you...

```
var myString = "s1a174o10";
var matches = myString.match(/([a-zA-Z]+)|(\d+)/g) || [];

for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i+=2){
    window[matches[i]] = matches[i+1];
}
```

WARNING: s,a,o will be global here. If you want, you can declare an object instead of using  `window` here.

Comment: This works for the given string, but minitech's answer is more robust since it will work for strings that aren't exactly of that format, like "24a1b2c3". That's because his RegEx expects a number after a character, where yours assumes it starts with string. See http://jsfiddle.net/2YL3z/2/